# Null variable and null View in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, null, switch-statement

I am working with a NavigationDrawer and Fragments. I have the Fragment written above that has a switch in it. I need to get if the switch is activated or not to use it as a parameter for a method but when I call the switch after I declared it, the variable gives me `null` as well as the `View`.

EDIT: The problem is that the fragment creates the view in `OnCreateView` and shows everything correctly on the screen, but when I try to access `rootview` within a method to modify `switchP` it gives me null and I don't know why.

```
Switch switchP;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.valor_unico, container, false);

    switchP = (Switch) rootview.findViewById(R.id.switchP);

    return rootview;
}


public String processProp(String prop) {
    switch ( calc.controlarSintaxis(prop)){
        case 0:
            return calc.resultadoValUnico(prop, switchP.isActivated());
        case 1:
            return "Error";
        case -1:
            return "Other error";
        default: return null;
    }
}
```

Here is the log of the error:

```
`04-10 14:26:24.142  15494-15494/com.hernan.calculadorlogicov31 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.hernan.calculadorlogicov31, PID: 15494
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3827)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4442)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18473)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3822)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4442)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18473)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
        dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.hernan.calculadorlogicov31.vista.ValorUnico.processProp(ValorUnico.java:40)
        at com.hernan.calculadorlogicov31.vista.Main.mostrarResultado(Main.java:101)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3822)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4442)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18473)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`
```

Comment: check if `switchP` and `rootview` being used before `onCreateView`

Comment: post logcat where it is getting null?

Comment: before `onCreateView` those variables are not in use, if I watch `switchP` during Debug it is succesfully created, assigned, but when the fragment is finally active it becomes null as well as the view of the fragment